# c++ dom parsing problem

Tags: xml-parsing

hi every body
i'm new to xercses C++dom parser.can anyone tell me

can we write  our own  getElementsBytagName,GetNodeValue etc function ?
how to write these function and use them in my code ?
can anybody explain me the process  of Dom parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xerces` provides methods like `getElementsBytagName` so you can use them in your application.

Have a look at [xerces programming guide](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/program-dom-3.html#UsingDOMAPI) you can find there how to `parse` xml file and how to get elements and attributes.

Comment: sorry for responding late ,the xerces programming guide it is quite unclear, i want to know can i use my own getElementBytagName means can i use my own implementation of this function or other such function

Comment: xerces is open source software so you can use your own functions, I guess you would navigate the three and get the elements that you are interested in - but maybe you should explain what you are trying to do and there might be better way than to reimplement existing functions.

Comment: hi thanx , i navigated the tree, i got my desired value ,i just edited it byt could not refelect the change , all i want to do is just make a change in a xml file my file got <value>name</value> i just want to change it  to <value>next</value>,and the change should be on the disk file too. mean when i open file next time i should get the changed value ,how i can do it , if you need the code for what i did just ask for it i will give it